# Create object by string

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a quick question, I hope you could help me with.

How can I use a string to navigate into a object?

If I have this:

```
var string = something;
```

And a object like this:

```
var this = {
    something: {
        other: "okay"
    }
}​;
```

How can I then use the string to do like this:

```
this.+string+.other
```

Which would be the same as:

```
this.something.other
```

?? Not a quick one maybe, but do you understand where I'm going?? :-)

Comment: careful with using `this` as a variable name. Strange things will happen, or nothing will happen at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `[]` below,

```
var _this = {
    something: {
        other: "okay"
    }
}​;

_this[string].other
```

**Note:** changed var name to `_this` as `var this = <..something..>` will throw you an error. Also `this` means currect execution object/window object in javascript.

Comment: +1 I also think that using `this` as a variable name is not that good.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The variables were just for the sake of example, but I should have been more careful :)

Answer (score 1):

Use square bracket notation:

```
var this[something].other
```